# Is there a comprehensive Big-O listing of Java data structures?

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

Question pretty much says it all.  Specifically, I would like the Big-O of all the methods within a structure, aside from the usual. The docs say very little about this.

**Addennum**

For those who are voting to close, I am not interested in the basic add, remove, iterator, etc
Those sources are fine for regularly used methods, but I am more interested in the algorithmic efficiency of the rest of the pile.

For example, what is the efficiency of `TreeMap.keySet()`?

Answer (score 2):

## **Java Collections Algorithm Efficiencies:** [Source](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027829.do)

### ArrayList

- get, set: **O(1)**
- add, remove: **O(n)**
- contains, indexOf: **O(n)**

### HashMap

- get, put, remove, containsKey: **O(1)**

### HashSet

- add, remove, contains: **O(1)**

### LinkedHashSet

- add, remove, contains: **O(1)**

### LinkedList

- get, set, add, remove (from either end): **O(1)**
- get, set, add, remove (from index): **O(n)**
- contains, indexOf: **O(n)**

### PriorityQueue

- peek: **O(1)**
- add, remove: **O(logn)**

### TreeMap

- remove, get, put, containsKey: **O(logn)**

### TreeSet

- add, remove, contains: **O(logn)**

Comment: When you remove an element in the array list, don't you have to step down the elements with the highest index?

Answer (score 0):

I would review the standard Big-O information about algorithms in [Introduction_to_Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

Comment: but how do you know what algorithms are used in java's classes?

Comment: The Java docs usually mention what algorithm is used for a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is there a spreadsheet or other list, but you can get this information in docs for every structure, for example [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Answer (score 0):

There really cannot be. Each JVM can have it's own runtime, with its own implementations. A few methods have specified O() characteristics, but the rest are whatever Sun, or Oracle, or IBM, or Apple, or Azul, does.

Comment: so why here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html is said "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)." JVM and classes implementation is different thing.

Comment: Are you sure that everybody who makes a JVM also reimplements all the JRE libraries?

Comment: @Anrey, I said, 'a few methods'. That's an example. @darioo, no of course not. But you can't predict.

Comment: Maybee it is true that some JVM don't have implementations that work in "guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).", but then this would be a bug. If the JavaDoc says it works in O(foo), then you can expect it to run at least in O(foo). If not write you should write a bug report.