# Time complexity of hash table and arraylist

Tags: java

Why is the time complexity of `haskey` is O(1). For finding a key it has to iterate all the element on the list so why it is O(1)
What is the time complexity of `contains` method of arraylist

Comment: Why not try a Google search!

Comment: Did not get the satisfactory answer

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100677/is-there-a-comprehensive-big-o-listing-of-java-data-structures/25338144#25338144

Comment: are you sure hash always has O(1)? what about collision?

Comment: ya @zerocool agree with you could provide me some link or information

Comment: okie..what exactly you don't understand? where are you stuck? can you probably update the question with your understanding and with what you dont understand. It will make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

A hashtable is not a list. It is a data structure specifically designed for O(1) lookup in the common case (the *worst-case* lookup is indeed O(n)). It achieves this by the notion of a *hash*, which is a number derived from the key's contents, used to directly calculate the index of the key in an array.

`ArrayList` is just an array underneath, so `contains` is what you would expect it to be for a linear-search structure.